# Setting xmx xms values for a Web Application

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Could anybody tell me what is the difference if we set xmx or xms values in eclipse.ini file ??
xmx xms values inside eclipse

and

xmx xms values inside Tomcat server ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, setting it in eclipse.ini will make Eclipse have the given memory settings, whereas if you set them "inside Tomcat server", then Tomcat will have the given memory settings. Tomcat and Eclipse are two different Java programs, and each runs in its own JVM. So each may have its own memory settings.

Comment: So ,  my understanding is if we want to add more memory to the tomcat server , we end up adding it in server ?? Am i right here ??

Comment: Yes, of course. Giving more memory to Eclipse won't give more memory to tomcat. They're different programs.